# Setting a component's variable to localStorage / global variable value on the initial render

Tags: initialization, global-variables, svelte, sveltekit, pageload

I'm using Svelte + SvelteKit.

I'd like to set *the initial* value of a variable in my component based on the user's previously saved value in `localStorage`. I can get it to load *after* the initial load using:

```
let foo = false;

if (browser) {
  foo = localStorage.collapsed === 'true'
}
```

This seems to run once the page has loaded, which in my case means there's a flash of the initial value.

I also know I can use `<svelte:head>` to get the initial `localStorage` value before the page renders:

```
<svelte:head>
  <script>
    if (localStorage.foo === 'true') {
      window.foo = true;
    }
  </script>
</svelte:head>
```

But how can I update my component's value based on this global variable / what's obtained in the `<head>`?

For CSS, I can attach a class to the `documentElement` or `body` but that doesn't help me here.

Repl: https://svelte.dev/repl/3e4099fc70814541ae837ff7da50926a?version=4.2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you forego server side rendering and defer the rendering until you are on the client it is not possible (there is no way for the server to know what a user has in localStorage).

You can wrap your entire component in `{#if browser}`, turn off SSR, and some other techniques.

Alternatively, store the data in a cookie, these are sent for every request and therefore available on the server.

Comment: Thanks, Stephane! I suppose using a cookie instead of `localStorage` is best for my use case then.